# DevOps Provision Azure Resources step is clearing my bot code if release aborted

Tags: azure-devops, botframework

I have a pipeline built where, simplified, it deploys a chatbot to a QA Bot Service and then, with a pre-deployment approval, to a PROD Bot Service. Normally it works fine. However, if I do not approve the release, my PROD Bot Service gets wiped (the project files are gone). I tried moving the approval to a post-deployment approval on the QA Bot Deployment, and I have the same exact issue. So my question is, why are my PROD Bot Service files being affected if that step is never being run? I need to be able to cancel the release without impacting the existing production code!

Edit: Updated with additional context. I have determined the issue is happening at provision Azure resources step. Somehow that is causing the code to clear out, before I get to ANY bot service deployment steps. Updated title as well to match issue.

Comment: it's really wired, not should happen. are you sure you QA step not touch in the PROD? can you share the pipeline?

Comment: Yes, I will share the full pipeline and an example of the aborted release which is causing the problem later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When you set the app service configuration settings, everything is cleared out except the settings you put in (annoying, but that's a whole other issue...). My issue was that I didn't have the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1` setting in the ARM template. Apparently, if you do not set this value, your bot code (if previously deployed from package via DevOps) will be cleared out. I never noticed this because if you finish the release, this value will be set by your Bot Service Deployment action, and we hadn't cancelled any releases (or had immediately redeployed).

In short, `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1` is required in the ARM template if you are setting any other app settings. Otherwise, bot code previously deployed by DevOps package will be cleared as soon as the provisioning step is completed. Adding this value fixed the issue.